# Functional Completeness

Tags: logic

I understand that showing function completeness is to use the symbols to generate the same truth values as if the other symbol would allow.

Out of the symbols {∧,∨,→,↔}, how would you generate the negation symbol '¬'

Comment: Not possible; you need the [False](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_(logic)) : $\bot$ constant.

Comment: Thanks @MauroALLEGRANZA. Is any longer justification to this. I can see that using those symbols, if you made a truth table, you can't ever make it false when its premises are true

Comment: See Lila Kari, [Adequate set of connectives](https://www.coursehero.com/file/24220696/adequate-conditionspdf/).

Comment: The problem was solved by [Post (1921)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2370324?origin=crossref&seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents).